# Unlocking a mutex after calling trylock()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I have a threaded server that can add/append/read files and relay data to the client.

If a file is being added, no other thread can append/read it. If a file is being appended, no threads can append/read it. If a file is being read, no other thread can append to it. However, if a file is being read, other files can read it.

Currently I have a mutex system that will do this, except it won't allow multiple reads.

To fix this, in the read method, I will change:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(fm->mutex));//LOCK
//do some things`
...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(fm->mutex));
```

to

```
pthread_mutex_trylock(&(fm->mutex));//TRYLOCK [NonBlocking, so the thread can continue the read]
//do some things`
...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(fm->mutex));
```

**Question**

How can I unlock the file without allowing the other methods (just append really) to begin writing to the file before all the other read()'s have finished?

**Example**

For example, if the reading thread that originally locked the file completes and unlocks the file and there are still other threads trying to read the file, then an appending thread gets the chance to lock the file and begin appending while the others are still reading, which is a no-no.

**Idea**

I want to keep a count of the number of threads currently reading a file. When a thread finishes, reduce the count. If the count is 0, meaning no threads are still reading, unlock the file. But, I'm worried that this would not be thread safe. If this is a viable solution, how could I make it thread safe? Another but, I believe only the original thread can successfully unlock the mutex.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for a read-write lock, which is provided by pthreads:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032t/index.html

Comment: How many state does a file can have? It seems me that at least three states, "Added"(state after that file is added", "Appended"(state after that file is appended" and "Read"(state after that file is added) are needed. One mutex may not be enough to control three states.

Comment: @Fumu Add/Append are essentially the same, they shouldn't be considered separate states. Only read is different, so I would say there are still only two states here.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That wasn't a pthread link... but searching for that in pthreads now. Edit: Whoops, just an example was linked somewhere else,  wasn't using pthreads.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Add that as the answer if you'd like, I've got working code now, very few changes were needed to get it running. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for a [read-write lock](http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_29.html), which is provided by pthreads.  It allows two modes of locking:  a shared/read-lock mode, which can be locked by multiple threads at once, and an exclusive/write-lock mode, where the lock call won't return until all other threads (readers and writers) have given up their hold on the lock.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a semaphore instead of the mutex (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065747/pthreads-mutex-vs-semaphore) about the differences).  The semaphore does thread-safe synchronized counting for you.

You can live without an additional mutex to lock the file for writing if you limit the number of simultaneous read accesses to a (sufficient large) number N and require the semaphore to be increased by that number for write access.  This way you can only gain write access if the number of readers is zero and all other readers will be locked out until your writer has finished.

Comment: Sounds like it would work. I have @JeremyFriesner's suggestion working, and luckily it was a much simpler solution. I do wonder if this is how that functionality was implemented though.

Comment: Semaphores are the easiest to count things in a thread-safe way (and they are implemented in pthreads).  As you need to keep track of the number of concurrent readers,  I bet they did it that way.  Mental note to myself: You have to look this thing up one day.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the POSIX documentation for [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) says:

> If successful, the *pthread_mutex_lock()*, *pthread_mutex_trylock()*, and *pthread_mutex_unlock()* functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

Since you don't show your code testing the return values, you don't know whether your lock operations (in particular) succeeded or not.

Separately, since you want a read/write lock, why not use one:

- [`pthread_rwlock_rdlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html)
- [`pthread_rwlock_wrlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.html)
- [`pthread_rwlock_unlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_unlock.html)
- [`pthread_rwlock_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_init.html)
- [`pthread_rwlock_destroy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html)

There are four `pthread_rwlockattr_*()` functions and a total of 9 `pthread_rwlock_*()` functions; I only listed the most important functions in the family.