# What is POSIX's equivalent of Win32's Mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads

POSIX's `mutex` is equivalent to Win32's `CRITICAL_SECTION` -- its scope is limited to a single process. Win32's mutex (Actually called a "mutant" in NT land) serves as a cross process locking mechanism. What is pthreads' equivalent for cross-process locks?

Comment: `CRITICAL_SECTION` is closer to `pthread_spinlock_t`, mutex would be `WaitForSingleObject`/`ReleaseMutex` vs. `pthread_mutex_t`.

Comment: @Steve-o: What is the difference between those two? To my (albeit limited) understanding, the only difference between a critical section and a mutex is that one is within a single process, while the other is cross-process. What then is the diffrence between the posix spinlock and the posix mutex?

Comment: @Billy: This answer might help, spinlocks busy-wait, mutexes yield   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195853/spinlock-versus-semaphore

Comment: @Steve-o: Critical sections yield.

Comment: @Billy: you can set it not to on multi-processor systems: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Steve-o: You can use the optimization of not always yielding, but you're in general not going to use up an entire time slice spinning for a critical section.

Comment: Also Mutex-with-spinlock on Windows is equivalent to PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP option on mutex in Linux (only).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pthread_mutex_t with a [pshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) attribute set to PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED . However, you're responsible to place such a mutex in shared memory, that all processes can access - so it's not as simple as the win32 api.

Perhaps closer to win32 is a [posix](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) or sysv semaphore. Traditionally, synchronization across processes has also been done using file locks e.g. flock or [lockf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lockf.html) (this is in no way as slow as it might sound)

Comment: Doesn't scope only apply to threads? You can only pass `pthread_attr_t` to `pthread_create`. You need to use `pthread_mutexattr_t` with `pthread_mutex_init`.

Comment: You're right, it's the pshared of pthread_mutexattr you'll need

Comment: Do you have a link on the slowness (or lack thereof) of locks? I searched for more detail on that but haven't found anything interesting. We have a big project with big shared files and I suspect we have some performance problems because of the locks, but I have no idea how to find out.

Comment: Using filesystem-based locks will take a good 5000-20000 cycles per lock or unlock operation; syscall overhead is incurred regardless of whether there is contention. With mutexes, the only overhead is your cpu's memory synchronization penalty unless there is contention. Using `lockf` may be acceptable for rarely-used locks, but for anything performance-oriented, forget it.

Comment: Thank you R. it's even worse than that because the files are mapped in memory and modified by memory operation. I dare not imagine what the kernel has to do detect a modification in the locked part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IPC for cross-process operations: pipes, semaphores, message queues, or shared memory.
I think in your case named semaphores would be fine. For more information:

```
man 7 sem_overview
```

Comment: I do want to use shared memory. But there still needs to be a way to perform locks on that shared memory.

Comment: sem_init() can be used to perform locks on shared memory.

Comment: Forget this useless semaphore stuff. Create a shared memory object and then create a pshared mutex in it.