# Is sem_post/sem_wait significantly faster than pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock?

Tags: objective-c, c, unix

I have a block of code that needs to run fast, right now I'm using  `pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock` to sync the threads but I saw that it has a certain impact on performance. I was wondering, if anyone ever benchmarked this, is `sem_post/sem_wait` **significantly** faster than `pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock`?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this based on @Giovanni answer, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195853/spinlock-versus-semaphore) Seems to put some light into it.

Comment: IMO, you're looking in the wrong place. If locking primitives are taking enough time to notice, you need to concentrate on a design with less locking, not on a faster locking primitive. Unfortunately, a lot of homework (and such) deliberately uses really terrible designs so you have to do synchronization a lot to help teach about synchronization. In reality, synchronization should be relatively unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say a semaphore is probably slower than a mutex because a semaphore has a superset of the mutex behavior. You can try something at user level such as spin lock that runs without kernel support, but it all depends on the rate of lock/unlocks and the contention.

Comment: "it has a superset of its behavior" could you please explain?:D

Comment: A mutex only allow 1 thread to be "inside". It only needs to test if someone is already there. A semaphore allows N threads to be "inside" (N can be =1). It must test how many post have been done.

Comment: mm..I see, then I think it makes sense to use a mutex, probably my problem it's elsewhere, maybe I have to find a way NOT to take and put the lock so often, I'll try to find other ways of optimizing then...Thanks

Comment: Try using profiling to identify precisely the source of the problem.

Comment: @Giovanni: semaphores (in general) don't implement the concept of "owner", so I'd rather say that they do less then mutexes. If you use a semaphore instead of a mutex, it's on you to implement the "ownership".

Comment: Regular mutexes don't have a concept of owner either, at least not in a testable way (any operation that would test the owner has undefined behavior). Only recursive and error-checking mutexes have testable owners.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is **not** significantly faster. They are implemented using same lower level primitives (read spin-locks and system calls). The real answer though would only be comparing both in *your* particular situation.

Comment: Mmm, how can this depend on context? I mean, is it possible that for block of code mutext could be faster and for another slower than a semaphore? Why?

Comment: It can depend on how you structure your application. Synchronization mechanisms have different **goals** not only different **means**.

Comment: Your particular OS/library/revision/phase of the moon matters. Code was created by humans, not gods.

Comment: At this level you will measure noise, not actual difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect them to be roughly the same speed, but you could always benchmark it yourself if you really care. With that said, POSIX semaphores do have *one*, and as far as I'm concerned *only one*, advantage over the more sophisticated primitives like mutexes and condition variables: `sem_post` is required to be async-signal-safe. It is the *only* synchronization-related function which is async-signal-safe, and it makes it possible to perform minimal interaction between threads from a signal handler! - something which would otherwise be impossible without much heavier tools like pipes or SysV IPC which don't interact well with the performance-oriented pthread idioms.

**Edit:** For reference, the simplest implementation of `pthread_mutex_trylock`:

```
if (mutex->type==PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT) return atomic_swap(mutex->lock, EBUSY);
else /* lots of stuff to do */
```

and the simplest implementation of `sem_trywait`:

```
int val = sem->val;
return (val>0 && atomic_compare_and_swap(sem->val, val, val-1)==val) ? 0 : EAGAIN;
```

Assuming an optimal implementation, I would guess that a mutex lock might be slightly faster, but again, benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Objective C your environment may be close enough to Cocoa to be able to use Grand Central Dispatch which would probably be even faster and definitely be even easier

Comment: I quote, try Grand Central Dispatch if you can, it is extremely fast and easy to use.