# When should one use a spinlock instead of mutex?

Tags: synchronization, mutex, spinlock

I think both are doing the same job,how do you decide which one to use for synchronization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spinlock Versus Semaphore!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195853/spinlock-versus-semaphore)

Comment: Mutex and Semaphore are not the same thing, so I don't think this is a duplicate. The Answer of the referenced article states this correctly.

For more details see http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Mutex-Semaphore

Answer (score 928, accepted):

**The Theory**

In theory, when a thread tries to lock a mutex and it does not succeed, because the mutex is already locked, it will go to sleep, immediately allowing another thread to run. It will continue to sleep until being woken up, which will be the case once the mutex is being unlocked by whatever thread was holding the lock before. When a thread tries to lock a spinlock and it does not succeed, it will continuously re-try locking it, until it finally succeeds; thus it will not allow another thread to take its place (however, the operating system will forcefully switch to another thread, once the CPU runtime quantum of the current thread has been exceeded, of course).

**The Problem**

The problem with mutexes is that putting threads to sleep and waking them up again are both rather expensive operations, they'll need quite a lot of CPU instructions and thus also take some time. If now the mutex was only locked for a very short amount of time, the time spent in putting a thread to sleep and waking it up again might exceed the time the thread has actually slept by far and it might even exceed the time the thread would have wasted by constantly polling on a spinlock. On the other hand, polling on a spinlock will constantly waste CPU time and if the lock is held for a longer amount of time, this will waste a lot more CPU time and it would have been much better if the thread was sleeping instead.

**The Solution**

Using spinlocks on a single-core/single-CPU system makes usually no sense, since as long as the spinlock polling is blocking the only available CPU core, no other thread can run and since no other thread can run, the lock won't be unlocked either. IOW, a spinlock wastes only CPU time on those systems for no real benefit. If the thread was put to sleep instead, another thread could have ran at once, possibly unlocking the lock and then allowing the first thread to continue processing, once it woke up again.

On a multi-core/multi-CPU systems, with plenty of locks that are held for a very short amount of time only, the time wasted for constantly putting threads to sleep and waking them up again might decrease runtime performance noticeably. When using spinlocks instead, threads get the chance to take advantage of their full runtime quantum (always only blocking for a very short time period, but then immediately continue their work), leading to much higher processing throughput.

**The Practice**

Since very often programmers cannot know in advance if mutexes or spinlocks will be better (e.g. because the number of CPU cores of the target architecture is unknown), nor can operating systems know if a certain piece of code has been optimized for single-core or multi-core environments, most systems don't strictly distinguish between mutexes and spinlocks. In fact, most modern operating systems have hybrid mutexes and hybrid spinlocks. What does that actually mean?

A hybrid mutex behaves like a spinlock at first on a multi-core system. If a thread cannot lock the mutex, it won't be put to sleep immediately, since the mutex might get unlocked pretty soon, so instead the mutex will first behave exactly like a spinlock. Only if the lock has still not been obtained after a certain amount of time (or retries or any other measuring factor), the thread is really put to sleep. If the same code runs on a system with only a single core, the mutex will not spinlock, though, as, see above, that would not be beneficial.

A hybrid spinlock behaves like a normal spinlock at first, but to avoid wasting too much CPU time, it may have a back-off strategy. It will usually not put the thread to sleep (since you don't want that to happen when using a spinlock), but it may decide to stop the thread (either immediately or after a certain amount of time; this is called "yielding") and allow another thread to run, thus increasing chances that the spinlock is unlocked (you still have the costs of a thread switch but not the costs of putting a thread to sleep and waking it up again).

**Summary**

If in doubt, use mutexes, they are usually the better choice and most modern systems will allow them to spinlock for a very short amount of time, if this seems beneficial. Using spinlocks can sometimes improve performance, but only under certain conditions and the fact that you are in doubt rather tells me, that you are not working on any project currently where a spinlock might be beneficial. You might consider using your own "lock object", that can either use a spinlock or a mutex internally (e.g. this behavior could be configurable when creating such an object), initially use mutexes everywhere and if you think that using a spinlock somewhere might really help, give it a try and compare the results (e.g. using a profiler), but be sure to test both cases, a single-core and a multi-core system before you jump to conclusions (and possibly different operating systems, if your code will be cross-platform).

### Update: A Warning for iOS

Actually not iOS specific but iOS is the platform where most developers may face that problem: If your system has a thread scheduler, that does not guarantee that any thread, no matter how low its priority may be, will eventually get a chance to run, then spinlocks can lead to permanent deadlocks. The iOS scheduler distinguishes different classes of threads and threads on a lower class will only run if no thread in a higher class wants to run as well. There is no back-off strategy for this, so if you permanently have high class threads available, low class threads will never get any CPU time and thus never any chance to perform any work.

The problem appears as follow: Your code obtains a spinlock in a low prio class thread and while it is in the middle of that lock, the time quantum has exceeded and the thread stops running. The only way how this spinlock can be released again is if that low prio class thread gets CPU time again but this is not guaranteed to happen. You may have a couple of high prio class threads that constantly want to run and the task scheduler will always prioritize those. One of them may run across the spinlock and try to obtain it, which isn't possible of course, and the system will make it yield. The problem is: A thread that yielded is immediately available for running again! Having a higher prio than the thread holding the lock, the thread holding the lock has no chance to get CPU runtime. Either some other thread will get runtime or the thread that just yielded.

Why does this problem not occur with mutexes? When the high prio thread cannot obtain the mutex, it won't yield, it may spin a bit but will eventually be sent to sleep. A sleeping thread is not available for running until it is woken up by an event, e.g. an event like the mutex being unlocked it has been waiting for. Apple is aware of that problem and has deprecated `OSSpinLock` as a result. The new lock is called `os_unfair_lock`. This lock avoids the situation mentioned above as it is aware of the different thread priority classes. If you are sure that using spinlocks is a good idea in your iOS project, use that one. Stay away from `OSSpinLock`! And under no circumstances implement your own spinlocks in iOS! If in doubt, use a mutex. macOS is not affected by this issue as it has a different thread scheduler that won't allow any thread (even low prio threads) to "run dry" on CPU time, still the same situation can arise there and will then lead to very poor performance, thus `OSSpinLock` is deprecated on macOS as well.

Comment: superb explaination... I have a doubt regarding spinlock i,e can i use a spinlock in ISR ? if no why not

Comment: @Mecki If I'm not mistaken, I believe you suggested in your answer that time slicing only occurs on single-processor systems. This is not correct! You can use a spin lock on a single-processor system and it will spin until its time quantum expires. Then another thread of the same priority can take over (just like what you described for multi-processor systems).

Comment: @fumoboy007 "and it will spin until its time quantum expires" // Which means you waste CPU time/battery power for absolutely nothing w/o any single benefit, which is utterly moronic. And no, I nowhere said that time slicing only happens on single core systems, I said on single core systems there is *ONLY* time slicing, while there is *REAL* parallelism om multicore systems (and also time slicing, yet irrelevant for what I wrote in my reply); also you entirely missed the point on what a hybrid spinlock is and why it works well on single and multicore systems.

Comment: @Mecki Huh what's the difference between spin locks on single-processor systems and spin locks on multi-processor systems? They waste CPU cycles on both, no?

Comment: @fumoboy007 Thread A holds the lock and is interrupted. Thread B runs and wants the lock, but cannot get it, so it spins. On a multicore system, Thread A can continue to run on another core while Thread B is still spinning, release the lock, and Thread B can continue within its current time quantum. On a single core system, there is only one core Thread A could run to release the lock and this core is held busy by Thread B spinning. So there is no way the spinlock could ever be released before Thread B exceeded its time quantum and thus all spinning is just a waste of time.

Comment: "use mutexes, they are usually the better choice and most modern systems will allow them to spinlock for a very short amount of time" I could prove this. I tried a multi-thread application and benchmark Mutex VS spinlock. I cannot observe an obvious performance boost

Comment: If you want to learn more about *spinlocks* and *mutexes* implemented in Linux kernel, I highly recommend reading [chapter 5](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) of great [*Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition* (LDD3)](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) (mutexes: page 109; spinlocks: page 116).

Comment: One case of having to use mutex is that user wants the synchronization be robust.. Only robust mutex available currently.

Comment: @FaceBro Please explain what you mean by "robust"? If you are talking about memory order, there are spinlocks that include a full memory barrier, just like a mutex will be.

Comment: @Mecki robust mutex that will be able to restore when holding thread crashes

Comment: Can you help on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53919851/7813604 ?, since I don't know how to apply your answer on it.

Comment: @Mecki "Using spinlocks on a single-core/single-CPU system makes usually no sense, since as long as the spinlock polling is blocking the only available CPU core, no other thread can run and since no other thread can run, the lock won't be unlocked either" doesn't this contradict your previous statement : "however, the operating system will forcefully switch to another thread, once the CPU runtime quantum of the current thread has been exceeded, of course" ?

Comment: This answer is way better than a week spent in college on mut-excess.

Comment: When using c# async code, the only reliable lock I have found so far is `SemaphoreSlim`. The old thread based `lock(object)` type of locks will not even pass the compiler any more and other types of locks are likely to give you a `SynchronizationLockException` with the message "The calling thread does not hold the lock" when releasing the lock. Especially when calling other async methods while holding the lock. The await async concepts have really destroyed the clear "one stack per thread" idea, and it's hard to trace the stack-tree in debugging as well as exception logs.

Answer (score 8):

Continuing with Mecki's suggestion, this article [pthread mutex vs pthread spinlock](http://www.alexonlinux.com/pthread-mutex-vs-pthread-spinlock) on Alexander Sandler's blog, Alex on Linux shows how the `spinlock` & `mutexes` can be implemented to test the behavior using #ifdef.

However, be sure to take the final call based on your observation, understanding as the example given is an isolated case, your project requirement, environment may be entirely different.

Answer (score 8):

Mecki's answer pretty well nails it.  However, on a single processor, using a spinlock might make sense when the task is waiting on the lock to be given by an Interrupt Service Routine.  The interrupt would transfer control to the ISR, which would ready the resource for use by the waiting task.  It would end by releasing the lock before giving control back to the interrupted task.  The spinning task would find the spinlock available and proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully agree with this answer. One a single processor, if a task holds a lock on a resource, then the ISR cannot safely proceed and cannot wait for the task to unlock the resource (since the task holding the resource was interrupted). In such cases, the task should simply disable interrupts to enforce exclusion between itself and the ISR. Of course, this would have to be done for very short time intervals.

Comment: @user1202136
"waiting on the lock to be given by an Interrupt Service Routine." He means the ISR will unlock the resource.

Answer (score 6):

Please also note that on certain environments and conditions (such as running on windows on dispatch level >= DISPATCH LEVEL), you cannot use mutex but rather spinlock.
On unix - same thing.

Here is equivalent question on competitor stackexchange unix site:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/why-are-spin-locks-good-choices-in-linux-kernel-design-instead-of-something-more

Info on dispatching on windows systems:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/IRQL_thread.doc

Answer (score 5):

Spinlock and Mutex synchronization mechanisms are very common today to be seen.

Let's think about Spinlock first.

Basically it is a busy waiting action, which means that we have to wait for a specified lock is released before we can proceed with the next action. Conceptually very simple, while implementing it is not on the case. For example: If the lock has not been released then the thread was swap-out and get into the sleep state, should do we deal with it? How to deal with synchronization locks when two threads simultaneously request access ?

Generally, the most intuitive idea is dealing with synchronization via a variable to protect the critical section. The concept of Mutex is similar, but they are still different. Focus on: CPU utilization. Spinlock consumes CPU time to wait for do the action, and therefore, we can sum up the difference between the two:

In homogeneous multi-core environments, if the time spend on critical section is small than use Spinlock, because we can reduce the context switch time. (Single-core comparison is not important, because some systems implementation Spinlock in the middle of the switch)

In Windows, using Spinlock will upgrade the thread to DISPATCH_LEVEL, which in some cases may be not allowed, so this time we had to use a Mutex (APC_LEVEL).

Answer (score 1):

The rule for using spinlocks is simple: use a spinlock if and only if the real time the lock is held is bounded and sufficiently small.

Note that usually user implemented spinlocks DO NOT satisfy this requirement because they do not disable interrupts. Unless pre-emptions are disabled, a pre-emption whilst a spinlock is held violates the bounded time requirement.

Sufficiently small is a judgement call and depends on the context.

Exception: some kernel programming must use a spinlock even when the time is not bounded. In particular if a CPU has no work to do, it has no choice but to spin until some more work turns up.

Special danger: in low level programming take great care when multiple interrupt priorities exist (usually there is at least one non-maskable interrupt). In this higher priority pre-emptions can run even if interrupts at the thread priority are disabled (such as priority hardware services, often related to the virtual memory management). Provided a strict priority separation is maintained, the condition for bounded real time must be relaxed and replaced with bounded system time at that priority level. Note in this case not only can the lock holder be pre-empted but the spinner can also be interrupted; this is generally not a problem because there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Spinlocks can actually perform *very poorly* on NUMA machines.  The issue is easy to understand and very hard to fix (without switching to a mutex, that is).  Consider a spinlock that lives in DRAM "near" core A, and threads on A and B contending for that lock.  Assume that B is remote from this DRAM.  As we all know, this means that memory accesses by A will be 5x or so faster than memory accesses by B, because B's accesses will need to traverse the bus of the NUMA chip, while A's accesses are local and hence avoid that bus traversal.

In effect, A's spin logic will run 5x or more faster than B's.  Yes, they contend, and B disrupts A, but the impact is asymmetric: when A wins the race to access the lock next, it will be getting local loads and stores, and hence will be spinning at a much higher instruction rate.  When B is spinning, those remote loads and stores will be slow, so B spins in slow motion.

The upshot, and we have observed this in our work on [Derecho](https://GitHub.com/Derecho-Project), is that we obtain a very unfair spinlock.  A is strongly favored over B, and locking by B will take a very long time.

How would you observe this?  In our case, we use [LibFabrics](https://www.openfabrics.org/libfabrics-a-user-perspective/#:%7E:text=Libfabric%20is%20supported%20by%20a%20variety%20of%20open,how%20to%20use%20and%20adapt%20from%20user%20perspective.), and that library has a few threads that get scattered over multiple cores.  Within the LibFabric logic, A and B are spinning to lock and then check a completion queue associated with RDMA hardware.  So the effect is that A gets to check this queue 5x more often than B.  In cases where an action by B is needed (the completed operation at the head of that queue is owned by B), A effectively starves B for access -- slowing down LibFabrics in an extreme way, that snowballed to greatly impact our Derecho code.  We've seen cases where A's access is so strongly favored that B might wait as long as 10ms for the lock -- even though under uncontended situations, B would grab this lock in 0.2us.  So, the effect can be quite extreme.

Conclusion?  Don't even consider using a spinlock on a NUMA system where your threads might be (1) on different NUMA cores, (2) with different locality to the DRAM where the spinlock was allocated.  You will see massive performance issues!  (3) When using a third-party library that has multiple threads, keep in mind that they may not have read this discussion and might have it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Spinlock is very lightweight and usually disables interrupts and spins on smp. A mutex has many lore requirements. A mutex is sleeping lock. It contains a queue on which threads can be placed when they are waiting for the mutex. When the mutex is released, the os can switch directly to the first unblocked thread. The queue is also usually priority based meaning that the highest priority thread will be able to run right away. Spinlocks dont have any of this and are primarily designed to handle concurrency between cpus.

Answer (score -7):

> Using spinlocks on a single-core/single-CPU system makes usually no sense, since as long as the spinlock polling is blocking the only available CPU core, no other thread can run and since no other thread can run, the lock won't be unlocked either. IOW, a spinlock wastes only CPU time on those systems for no real benefit

This is wrong. There is no wastage of cpu cycles in using spinlocks on uni processor systems, because once a process takes a spin lock , preemption is disabled , so as such, there could be no one else spinning! It's just that using it doesn't make any sense! Hence, spinlocks on Uni systems are replaced by preempt_disable at compile time by the kernel!

Comment: The quoted is still entirely true. If the compiled result of the source code doesn't contain spinlocks, then the quoted is irrelevant. Assuming what you said is true about the kernel replacing spinlocks at compile time, how are spinlocks handled when precompiled on another machine which may or may not be uniprocessor, unless we're strictly talking about spinlocks only in the kernel itself?

Comment: "Once a process takes a spin lock, preemption is disabled". Preemption is not disabled when a process takes a spin. If that was the case, a single process could take down the entire machine by just entering a spinlock and never leaving. Note that if your thread runs in the kernel space (instead of user space), taking a spin lock does indeed disable preemption, but I don't think that's what is being discussed here.

Comment: At *compile time* by *the kernel*?

Comment: @konstantin FYI spin lock can only be taken in kernel space. And when a spin lock is taken preemption is disabled on the local processor.

Comment: @hydranix Didn't get you?Obviously you cannot compile a module against a kernel in which  CONFIG_SMP is enabled, and run the same module on a kernel which has CONFIG_SMP disabled.