# C++ (CAS-like) synchronization on getter and setter of user defined types

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, lock-free

Suppose there is a user defined class `MyClass` that has a setter and a getter function.

```
class MyClass {
    int m_value;
    public:
        void set(int value)
        { m_value = value; }

        int get() const
        { return m_value;}
};
```

And there is a function `increment()` that can increase the value of the object by 1, which may be invoked in multiple threads.

```
void increment(MyClass& myClass)
{
    myClass.set(myClass.get() + 1);
}
```

What is the best way to make this function thread-safe? By just using a lock? Is there any way to achieve it by using some CAS-like operations?

Comment: It's unlikely you need atomics and they may even be slower, better to just protect the class' data with a mutex.

Comment: You could of course add the myClass::increment() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using **C++11**, you could just use `std::atomic<int>` which provides atomic [load](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load), [store](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store) and [increment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) which seems to be everything you need.

I suspect you don't need atomics though as in most cases they will be slower than your basic mutex.

See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308328/c11-is-synchronizing-with-stdmutex-slower-than-with-stdatomicmemory-orde) before you make your decision.

Comment: I don't thinke `std::atomic<int>` will work because I am using a user defined type. Thanks for the advice and the link.

Comment: So really your only solution is to protect it with a mutex then. Simplifies the decision ;)

Comment: I also mean to use std::atomic<int> internally in your MyClass. If that is what you meant by user defined type.

Comment: Even though I use atomic internally, the `increment()` is not thread-safe because two threads can set the same value simultaneously.

Comment: @user571470 they can't do that if the value is atomic. The increment operations get sequenced. What is unsafe is your `Increment` function. You should provide the means to increment the value without reading, then writing.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of using `std::atomic` or `std::mutex` inside the `increment()` member function?

Comment: See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0aa11350d653bb2 Both of these are free of data races, but depending on how you use them, they may not be logically correct. Such is the difficulty in making a class thread safe.

Comment: Yes, if it's logically correct, the function should be changed to

void increment(MyClass& myClass)
{
    LockGuard guard;
    myClass.set(myClass.get() + 1);
}

Answer (score -3):

Use std::mutex and enjoy

```
    #include <mutex>

    class MyClass 
    {
        int m_value;
        std::mutex mtx;

        void set(int value) 
        {
            mtx.lock();
            m_value = value;
            mtx.unlock();
        }

        int get() const 
        {
            return m_value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work. The `increment()` is still not thread-safe.

Comment: increment() not need thread-safe because MyClass.set function is thread-safe.

Comment: but two threads can call set() with the same value, which is not the idea of incrementing the value twice.