# Hybrid mutex library for Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking, mutex, spinlock

Is there any standard threading library for Linux which implements hybrid mutex capabilities? I mean, a mutex which, at first, "behaves like a spinlock" and "only if the lock has still not been obtained after a certain amount of time (or retries or any other measuring factor), the thread is really put to sleep", as mentioned by Mecky at [When should one use a spinlock instead of mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869825/when-should-one-use-a-spinlock-instead-of-mutex/5870415#5870415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glibc already provides this.  Just use the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP` type or use `PTHREAD_ADAPTIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` as the mutex initializer.

See http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c#l90