# Kernel programming : wait queue uses spinlock internally

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on implementing blocking calls in char device drivers. I use wait_queue_head_t element with `wait_queue_interruptible` and `wake_up_interruptible` calls. What I understand and read about blocking behaviour is that when a call is blocked it sleeps( not busy wait) and doesn't consume resources. But when I checked `struct wait_queue_head` in `wait.h` , it uses a `spin-lock`. spin-locks have behaviour of not sleeping (busy waiting)..! So this confused me. Any clarifications to help on this please? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please have a look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869825/when-should-one-use-a-spinlock-instead-of-mutex).

Answer (score 2):

The  purpose of spinlock you find in

```
struct __wait_queue_head {
spinlock_t lock;
struct list_head task_list;
```

};

is to protect the member task_list from concurrent access.
If you step in wait_queue_interruptible() you could find a call to schedule().

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answer: the spinlock inside the `struct wait_queue_head` is used to protect the internal list member in case multiple threads are accessing it simultaneously.  However, the spinlock is never held when going to sleep -- it is only held during the small, non-preemptable, non-sleeping critical sections that manipulate the wait queue internals.