# Is there any Spinlock defined in Qt? If not how can we Implement it?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, qt5, thread-synchronization

I am not able to find any spinlock in Qt library. Does Qt don't have any? How can we implement cross-platform(Win-Linux-Mac) spinlock in Qt?

Qt 5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html

Qt 4: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-synchronizing.html

Comment: You may use any alomic types. Qt or STL.

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/aperezdc/5582452

Comment: There is QLockFile or QSharedMemory, which could be used for this

Comment: erk... may I ask why do you possibly need a spinlock, yet you don't know how to implement one?

Comment: Perhaps if you described the problem you are trying to solve (with spinlocks) instead of the solution you are looking for, you might get some better responses. It's been a long time since I have actually needed a true spinlock, usually there are other mechanisms that are more CPU friendly available.

Comment: Why not using a QMutex? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869825/when-should-one-use-a-spinlock-instead-of-mutex